# Getting user input value from ArcGIS web app

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcade, arcgis-api-wpf

I want to have user input an integer value which can then be used in an Arcade expression (for example in a popup menu).

Is there a way to do this on
ArcGIS Online?

I am looking for a solution that will work on ArcGIS Online without requiring installation or server setup. Arcade doesn't have support for user input. I tried creating a text box with HTML code in a popup but I couldn't find a way to pass the value to Arcade...

Comment: I don't understand the thinking behind downvoting -1 a question without providing any feedback...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have kind of answered your own question. Lets break it down.

- Arcade doeson't support user input. - Ill take your word on this as I haven't tried, but given its more expression based, then this sounds about right.

What Arcade CAN do though, is access values from a data source.

So perhaps a design consideration is to

- Have te user input their value into a popup menu that you can build using ArcGIS Online (https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/create-form-mv.htm) - This may require you to create a 'shell' dataset that the user input gets placed into.
- Then have your Arcade script run on the shell dataset where the user input is saved.

As an additional note, be wary of other features, like Geoforms, as these often have constraints around what type of dataset they can work.